# How to merge the overlapping parts of two triangular meshes?

Tags: cgal, open3d

I have the following image examples. How can I merge the two intersecting grids on the left to create the effect on the right?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ac1M9.jpg)

I would like to achieve this effect using C++ programming, but I don't know how to do it. Can you help me?